# Pulling array ID values?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key, key-value-store

I am attempting to write some PHP that places values in a 2D array and create a table to present the data. My problem comes when I try to create a button at the end of each row, I am trying to give it a unique name based off the $row['ID'] from the SQL query(the first dimension of the array). I just do not know how to pull this data in the loop context.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $list[$row['ID']]['ProductionNo']=$row['ProductionNo'];
    $list[$row['ID']]['UserID']=$row['UserID'];
    $list[$row['ID']]['StartTime']=$row['StartTime'];
    $list[$row['ID']]['EndTime']=$row['EndTime'];

    }

$openproduction = '<table><tbody><td>';
foreach ($list as &$value) 
    {
    $openproduction .= '<tr>';
        foreach ($value as &$valueitem)
        {
        $openproduction .= '<td> '.$valueitem.'</td>';
            }
    $openproduction .= "<td><input type='button' name='$key' class='button' ></td></tr></tr>";
    }
$openproduction .= '</tbody></td></table>';
unset($valueitem);
unset($value);
```

Comment: ok, should be a bit better

Comment: yep, great. :-) and it looks like since you fixed the code, people are starting to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
foreach ($list as &$value)
```

Use:

```
foreach ($list as $row_id => &$value)
```

Then you'll have a valid $row_id inside that loop that you can reference.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things you were doing were simply weird and in some cases incorrect, try something like this instead (you're making it way more complicated than it actually is):

```
$openProduction = "<table><tbody>";
$openProduction .= "<td>productionId</td>";
$openProduction .= "<td>userID</td>";
$openProduction .= "<td>startTime</td>";
$openProduction .= "<td>endTime</td>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $productionId = $row['ProductionNo']; 
    $userID = $row['UserID'];
    $startTime = $row['StartTime'];
    $endTime = $row['EndTime'];

    $openProduction .= "<tr id='row_$id'>";
         $openProduction .= "<td>$productionId</td>";
         $openProduction .= "<td>$userID</td>";
         $openProduction .= "<td>$startTime</td>";
         $openProduction .= "<td>$endTime</td>";
         $openProduction .= "<td><input type='button' id='button_$id' class='button' /></td>";
    $openProduction .= "</tr>";
}

$openProduction = ."</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: the code used before was to create a 2d array I can access elsewhere, this will create the table but not the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you want to do it in your own way then see the below code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $row_id=0;// This variable will denote row number. 
    $list[$row_id]['ProductionNo']=$row['ProductionNo'];
    $list[$row_id]['UserID']=$row['UserID'];
    $list[$row_id]['StartTime']=$row['StartTime'];
    $list[$row_id]['EndTime']=$row['EndTime'];
    $row_id++;
    }

$openproduction = '<table><tbody><td>';
foreach ($list as &$value) 
    {
    $openproduction .= '<tr>';
        foreach ($value as &$valueitem)
        {
        $openproduction .= '<td> '.$valueitem.'</td>';
            }
    $openproduction .= "<td><input type='button' name='$key' class='button' ></td></tr></tr>";
    }
$openproduction .= '</tbody></td></table>';
unset($valueitem);
unset($value);
```